# How to share my own facebook application to my friends

Tags: facebook

I developed a simple FB messenger bot app, the app was reviewed and approved by Facebook, it is live and working as expected, replying to messages from my Page users.

Now, I want to share my app to my friends, so they can use it to their Pages. However, I can't find a way to share it, I can't find the link for my App. Any hint on how to share my App will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "replying to messages from my Page users" - well, it is a messenger app? just share the link to your facebook page and tell them they should write a message to it....

Comment: I dont want to share my facebook page, i want my friends to use my messenger app in their facebook page.

Comment: then you have to create some external page for it, that's it